# Which Server is GoogleMaps SDK iOS contacting

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hello which server is the Google Maps SDK for iOS contacting to receive the new maps.

Is it still: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"?

EDIT:
Just found out that http://google.com should be sufficient.

Comment: Are you talking about the maps.app, in iOS 6 google maps is replaced by Apple maps.

Comment: I am talking about the new GoogleMaps SDK for iOS. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/), it makes POST requests to https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap to get its data.